# PostgreSQL agregation function with group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana

I try to get output from PostgreSQL into Grafana , but there is error

> db query error: pq: column "systemevents.receivedat" must appear in
> the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

This is the code

```
SELECT 
  $__timeGroupAlias(receivedat,$__interval),
  SUBSTRING(message, '(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}') AS the_address,
  COUNT(message) as cc 
FROM systemevents 
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(receivedat,$__interval)
GROUP BY the_address 
ORDER BY cc DESC
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the GROUP, e.g. (`1` refers to first column from the SELECT):

```
SELECT 
  $__timeGroupAlias(receivedat,$__interval),
  SUBSTRING(message, '(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}') AS the_address,
  COUNT(message) as cc 
FROM systemevents 
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(receivedat,$__interval)
GROUP BY 1, the_address 
ORDER BY cc DESC
```